# What is the correct syntax and structure for the wordforms.txt file in Sphinx?

Tags: sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I know it should be

horse > pony

but what if you want to do

horse > pony 
horse > donkey

?

I get a warning from sphinx on indexing saying

WARNING: duplicate wordform found - skipped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
horse > pony
donkey > pony
```

(Although this is pretty similar to your other question)

Comment: Thanks Pat, it similar to the other question now that I look at it.